# Grid: how to give all free space to one column?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid of 4 columns. It's content is not enough to fill all the space so there are some gaps in-between columns. How do I remove all gaps while giving all extra space to one column? I.e. how do I remove all gaps between 1&2 and 3&4 columns, while living the gap between 2&3 columns?
I want a flexible design, which scales when changing width of the table.

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  width: 100px; /* the rest of the code should not depend on this value!! */
}
```

```html
How it is:
<div>
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
</div>

How it should be:
<div>
<span>1</span>
<span>2------------</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6------------</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 5 column grid where the cenetr column is set to `auto`. This will make the center column occupy the remaining space. Then you can use `:nth-child(4n+3) { grid-column: 4 / 5; }` to prevent that the center column is filled with any elements:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content min-content auto min-content min-content;
}

div > span:nth-child(4n+3) {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span>6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span>8</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hm. Actually you don't need 5th column, you just make 2nd column auto, and that's it.

Comment: @klm123 only as long as you dont want to apply background or border styles to the elements.